# Looking to export datagridview

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, export

I have a scrolling datagridview that dyanmically changes it's number of columns and rows. I'm looking for a way to export the datagridview as it is when the user clicks a button. I want it to export as something that cannot be edited (so not excel file). I've tried using iTextSharp to export as pdf and can't seem to come up with a dynamically changing loop that would suit it. Also, I haven't been able to find any sample code using iTextSharp that included also exporting row headers along with column headers. I've also tried one solution (that I can't seem to find at the moment) on the microsoft forums that takes advantage of a the add-on functionality of Excel to write to PDF after the datagridview contents are exported to it. The problem I have with that is it creates way to many pages as well as still shows rows that have been hidden or deleted from the datagridveiw. Any idea of how I can accomplish this feat?

I'll include two pictures to show the way in which the datagridview is dynamically populated and changes

It can have up to 66 rows and 12 columns (not including row or column headers)
[image: datagridview example 1]

[image: datagridview example 2]

Comment: If the underlying data source is a `DataTable` you can read/write to/from XML by doing `myDataTable.WriteXml(nameOfFile)` or `myDataTable.ReadXml(nameOfFile)`.

Comment: I read in the data from an excel file that is a resource to the program, so I do not have a DataTable data source. How could I set it to the a datatable and populate it with the data from the datagridview?

Comment: It would need to be some sort of loop I'm assuming, since the size of my datagridview changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**EPPlus**](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to create an password-protected (locked) **excel file that can be read, but not edited**. I can show you how to start from a situation like this:

[image]

and get a protected file like this:

[image]

---

First you must download and include the [**EPPlus Library**](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) in your project. Don't forget to check the great [EPPlusSamples Project](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/89923)

Then you need a method to extract your DataGridView **VISIBLE** data (you don't want the invisible column to be exported). I did it using a 2d array. This function accept a `DataGridView` parameter and returns a 2d array:

```
Function GetDataGridView2DArray(ByVal dataGridView As DataGridView) As String(,)
    'Save list of visible columns
    Dim nrVisibleColumns = (From c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
               Where c.Visible
               Select c).ToList()

    'create 2d-array to store values, dimensions given by number of rows and visible columns
    Dim dgvArray(nrVisibleColumns.Count, DataGridView1.Rows.Count) As String

    'create the first row with Column Headers text
    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In nrVisibleColumns
        dgvArray(col.Index + 1, 0) = col.HeaderText
    Next

    'create Rows, including Row Header text
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim rowNumber = row.Index + 1
        dgvArray(0, rowNumber) = DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).HeaderCell.Value 'save rowheader cell value 

        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In nrVisibleColumns
            dgvArray(col.Index + 1, rowNumber) = DataGridView1(col.Index, row.Index).Value
        Next
    Next

    Return dgvArray
End Function
```

Now that you have your array you can create an **Excel File** and fill it with data. Plus, before saving, we'll lock it with a password to prevent user editing.

```
Private Sub CreateXls()
    Dim fi = New FileInfo("C:\temp\output.xlsx")
    Dim package As New ExcelPackage()

    Dim ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Dgv Output") 'create sheet

    'get array of datagridview data
    Dim dataArray = GetDataGridView2DArray(DataGridView1)

    'loop my 2d array and fill my excel file
    For iColumn As Integer = dataArray.GetLowerBound(0) To dataArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        For iRow As Integer = dataArray.GetLowerBound(1) To dataArray.GetUpperBound(1)
            ws.Cells(iRow + 1, iColumn + 1).Value = dataArray(iColumn, iRow)
            ws.Cells(iRow + 1, iColumn + 1).Style.Locked = True 'lock the cell
        Next 
    Next

    ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns() 'resize columns to fit
    ws.Protection.AllowFormatColumns = True 'let user resize columns if he wants
    ws.Protection.SetPassword("1") 'protect the sheet from editing

    package.SaveAs(fi) 'save file
End Sub
```

Now you should be able to easily export your dynamic **DataGridView** with one click.

Comment: Couldn't we just save the data as a pdf once we already have it exported to excel using a save as command (since excel supports a Save As PDF format) using this same method, but tweaked slightly?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder You can do it starting from the excel file you just created. Using Interop.Excel, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb407651(v=office.12).aspx)  The main problem with PDF is that you never know what kind of layout you're going to get... Especially with dynaminc row/columns you're probably going to get horrible results like half-empty pages, pages with only 1 row in it, or just 2 columns etc etc. Excel gives the end-user the possibility to print the file the way he wants, in the format he wants. (your question is tagged Excel, by the way).

Comment: I have an entirely different button that prints the datagridview however it is and it works with the dynamically changing nature of the datagridview (using a datagridview printer class), so that's why I was looking for purely a method of export. Printing would not be an issue, but I would like the chart to look half-way decent

Comment: @CaffeineCoder My answer(s) provide everything you want. Export datagridview, include row/column headers, exclude invisible columns, prevent editing. and then you can play around adding the interop code to take the excel file, save it as PDF and delete the previously created excel file. I guess it's all can do for you, good luck

Comment: You are right. I will fool around with the method you've provided to see if I can accomplish a save to pdf. If I'm able to get the desired result you'll be sure to get credit for the answer

Comment: @CaffeineCoder if you need more help just ask, but you're almost there ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is My Coding Tested And Output is Perfect :

```
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'create object of excel
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In Me.DataGridView1.Columns
            ExcelSheet.Cells(1, col.Index + 1) = col.HeaderText.ToString
            For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
                ExcelSheet.cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells("First Column Name").Value
                For j = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    ExcelSheet.cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With
    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    ExcelSheet = Nothing
    ExcelBook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing
```